# Among these two transistors, which has larger gm?

Tags: transistors, mosfet

Two transistors have same Vp and Vgs but transistor 2 has double Idss than transistor 1, which will show larger gm?

Comment: What do you think and why?

Comment: What have you found out so far about this problem? Can you show us your thinking so far?

Comment: I think we can use this equation,
 gm = [ (2Idss/Vp) (1 - (Vgs/Vp)) ]
and the answer would be the second transistor, but I need to confirm the answer.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! Is this homework?

Comment: @dhanshree we don't do peoples homework here. You need to show in the question that you have had a go yourself, explain your methods and where you get confused etc. Please edit the question to do this, and don't put the changes in the comments